# Can I run C++ in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++

I'm almost completely new to Android development, but can I use the new Android Studio to edit and run C++ code? Will I be able to import and use a C++ library with Android Studio in order to make an Android app?

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be possible with some wrapper like explained here : [android studio with cpp](http://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/) (not sure I did not try it) I suggest you to use Java as a programming language. You can also make your android application with unity by using C# or JavaScript if its a game.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Use android NDK for this: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html